# Basic javascript / JSON grabbing elements from list

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I have a PHP array of data $mainarray that I'm trying to manipulate with javascript.

I did this:

```
var masterdata = <?php echo json_encode($mainarray); ?>;
```

To check how that came through, I did this:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(masterdata, null, 4));
```

And I got this:

```
{
"Department":"Fire",
"Year":"2014",
"Amount":"311.3"
},
{
"Department":"Police",
"Year":"2014",
"Amount":"622.3"
},
{
"Department":"Vehicles",
"Year":"2014",
"Amount":"100.9"
}
...
```

I now just want to loop through every one of those bracketed sets and do something like

```
if (masterdata[Department] == "Fire" && masterdata[Year] == "2014") 
    fireamount2014 = masterdata[Amount];
```

but I think that syntax is nowhere close and I am going mad from lack of basic understanding of how this works.

Comment: Close. `masterdata[i]["Department"]` or `masterdata[i].Department`, assuming that you are in a loop with `i` as the counter. I.e., put quotes around the property names if using square brackets, or *don't* put quotes if using dot notation. (Also, note that you should use `console.log()` rather than `alert()` to debug the values of variables.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (var i in masterdata) {
    if (masterdata[i]['Department'] == 'Fire' && masterdata[i]['Year'] == '2014') {
        fireamount2014 = masterdata[i]['Amount'];
    }
}
```

This should work.

**EDIT**
It is also good practice to ensure that the key 'Department', 'Year' and 'Amount' exist first before accessing them by doing something like

```
if (masterdata[i]['Department'] !== undefined)
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe it was so simple yet so hard to find a relevant example anywhere I looked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce` to sum up the fire amounts for each year and pass it back as an object indexed by the year.

```js
const data = [{
  "Department": "Fire",
  "Year": "2014",
  "Amount": "311.3"
}, {
  "Department": "Police",
  "Year": "2014",
  "Amount": "622.3"
}, {
  "Department": "Vehicles",
  "Year": "2014",
  "Amount": "100.9"
}, {
  "Department": "Vehicles",
  "Year": "2015",
  "Amount": "100.9"
}]

console.log(
  data.reduce((acc, item) => {
    // set the default for the year
    if (!acc['FireAmount_' + item.Year]) {
      acc['FireAmount_' + item.Year] = 0
    }
    // increment the new amount on the the stored FireAmount
    acc['FireAmount_' + item.Year] += Number(item.Amount)
    return acc
  }, {})
)
```